# Desktop artefacts on Odin

Tags: desktop, odin

I have desktop artifacts, shadows etc when using apps like Firefox. My graphics system summary is:

```
description: VGA compatible controller
product: TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:65:00.0
version: a1
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
resources: irq:124 memory:d7000000-d7ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:b000(size=128) memory:d8000000-d807ffff
```

Anyone having a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Many users have those. It's related to GNOME Mutter window manager and apparently not that easy to fix/patch. You can google more about it and/or find just a few issues here:

https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues/80

https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/605